# Keras correlation coefficient as metric in R

Tags: r, keras, statistics

Does anyone know how to use the correlation coefficient or squared correlation coefficient as a metric in keras in R (although other languages may provide clues). This is for a CNN that functions similar to an image compressor/decompressor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also struggling with the same problem. Here's my go at a custom metric using keras backend functions.

```
  metric_correlation <- 
custom_metric("correlation", 
              function(y_true, y_pred){
                k_sqrt(k_sum((y_pred-k_mean(y_pred))*(y_true-k_mean(y_true)))/length(y_true))/
                  k_sqrt(k_var(y_true))/k_sqrt(k_var(y_pred))
              })
                                          
  model %>% compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam',metrics = metric_correlation)
```

Something is amiss though - correlation drops as the epochs increase

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30765615)